# Unit testing - ignoring module run block

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Is there a way to prevent an application run block from executing during unit tests?

My situation is that I have added some session checking logic to the run block, which redirects to a login page should session checks fail.

Now that I have added this run block in, all my other tests fail since they expect the login page to have been requested as I'm not ensuring the session check returns true before each test.

So is there a way to skip the run block for a unit test, or would it be something like mocking out the module in my tests so it doesn't have the run block included?

I'm probably thinking about this the wrong way, so please enlighten me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, run block is part of angular app lifecycle.

I would suggest not to have this logic in .run, but transfer all authentication logic into some service. After that its easy to mock it.

If you can be more specific about app architecture, I can suggest more improvements.